# Measurability condition $\{x \in X: g(\{n \in \mathbf{N}: f_n(x)>a\})>b\} \in \mathscr{F}$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,\mathscr{F})$ be a measurable space, and $f_n: X\to \mathbf{R}$ a sequence of measurable functions, with $n\ge 1$. Let also $g$ be a real-valued function defined on the power set of the positive integers $\mathbf{N}$.

What assumptions on $g$ are sufficient so that
$$
\{x \in X: g(\{n \in \mathbf{N}: f_n(x)>a\})>b\} \in \mathscr{F}
$$
for every real $a,b$?

Comment: What are the conditions on $f_n$? without any precision of that the answer can't be precise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us identify the power set of $\Bbb {N} $ with the set $P := \{0,1\}^\Bbb {N} $ of $0-1$ valued sequences.

Then, by measurability of the $f_n $, the map
$$
\Phi_a : X \to P, x \mapsto (1_{f_n (x)>a})_n
$$
is measurable when $P $ is equipped with the product sigma algebra.

Now, your set in question is equal to
$$
\{x \mid \Phi_a (x) \in g^{-1}((b,\infty))\},
$$
which is measurable if $g^{-1}((b,\infty)) $ is. This holds, if $g : P \to \Bbb {R} $ is measurable (with respect to the product sigma algebra on $P $).

I am very certain that this condition is even necessary,  if you want your condition to hold for all choices of $f_n $.

Comment: Sorry for the probably stupid question, but in this case does the product sigma algebra on $P$ coincide with its power set? In this case, $g: P \to \bf R$ is always measurable..

Comment: @Nduccio: No, it does not. The product sigma algebra is the same as the Borel sigma algebra of $P$ (equipped with the product topology). One can show (for example) that the product sigma algebra has the cardinality of the continuum, while that of the power set of $P$ is strictly larger than that.

Comment: @PhoemeuX: I have still a doubt on that, everything else is clear (thank you!). When you speak about the product sigma algebra on $P=\{0,1\}^{\bf N}$, what kind of sigma algebra are you setting on $\{0,1\}$? Then, why the product sigma algebra on $\{0,1\}^{\bf N}$ is different from its power set? Excuse me if it is a trivial question, but I dont see it

Comment: @Nduccio: On $\{0,1\}$, I use the discrete sigma algebra. But the product sigma algebra is generated by "cylinder" sets, where only **finitely** many factors are not equal to $\{0,1\}$. This makes the difference.

Comment: @PhoemeuX: That's fine, but what happens when you take countable intersections of these cylinders? I mean, if you take any $x=(x_n)_{n\ge 1} \in \{0,1\}^{\bf N}$ then $x$ can be seen as $\cap_{n\ge 1}(\{x_n\} \times \prod_{i\neq n}\{0,1\})$, isn't it?

Comment: @Nduccio: Yes, singletons are measurable. But this only shows that all **countable** subsets of $P =\{0,1\}^\Bbb {N} $ are measurable. We do not get measurability of every subset.

Comment: I got your point, thank you PhoemueX!